# Configure PhpStorm, Xdebug and Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, phpstorm, xdebug

I am using PhpStorm 2018.2.1 on Windows 10.

I have Homestead Vagrant box setup for Laravel. My Laravel application is working as expected. Recently I have configured Xdebug for my PHP 7.1 and configured PhpStorm according to [this article](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2018.2/configuring-remote-interpreters.html) but when I am starting to debug I am getting the following error:

```
vagrant://C:/Users/Suman/Homestead/usr/bin/php -dxdebug.remote_enable=1 -dxdebug.remote_mode=req -dxdebug.remote_port=9000 -dxdebug.remote_host=10.0.2.2 /home/vagrant/Code/news/app/Http/Controllers/HomeController.php
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Controller' not found in /home/vagrant/Code/news/app/Http/Controllers/HomeController.php on line 8
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /home/vagrant/Code/news/app/Http/Controllers/HomeController.php:0

Fatal error: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Controller' not found in /home/vagrant/Code/news/app/Http/Controllers/HomeController.php on line 8

Call Stack:
    0.1118     383032   1. {main}() /home/vagrant/Code/news/app/Http/Controllers/HomeController.php:0


Process finished with exit code 255
```

I don't know how to proceed from here. What could be the problem?

[image]

Comment: *"What could be the problem?"* You are doing it wrong. Right now you are 1) Trying to execute your script in a CLI environment (and not a web page) and 2) you are calling your `HomeController` class directly bypassing the whole framework code and therefore missing composer's class autoloader (that's why `Controller` class is not found). You need to do Web Page debug and not PHP Script (which is CLI environment). Start here: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Debugging+with+PhpStorm

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a configuration issue. It appears you are attempting to run your vagrant php scripts through your windows php interpreter?

```
vagrant://C:/Users/Suman/Homestead/usr/bin/php -dxdebug.remote_enable=1 - 
dxdebug.remote_mode=req -dxdebug.remote_port=9000 -dxdebug.remote_host=10.0.2.2 
/home/vagrant/Code/news/app/Http/Controllers/HomeController.php
```

Note that it is calling the interpreter here: c:/users/Suman/Homestead/usr/bin/php   but it is looking for a your controllers on the vagrant box '/home/vagrant/Code/news/app/Http/Controllers/HomeController.php

Although the files will be on your windows drive and you will mount them to your vagrant instance upon boot, all the work should be happening on the vagrant box itself. Phpstorm will edit the files through the windows machine, but the running and debugging will occur in the vagrant instance (in the mounted folder).